# Intuition behind independence of eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> **Theorem 6.14**: Eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues of A are linearly independent.

My prof already gave us a proof of the theorem, so I'm not looking for another one. Could someone please explain the intuition behind why the theorem above is true?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give the proof given by your professor, so that we can understand why the proof given by your professor is not intuitive or fill in the intuition in the proof?

Comment: @user17762 Sorry, I don't have the proof with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a bunch of eigenvectors under distinct eigenvalues $\{\mathbf{v}_1,\ \cdots,\ \mathbf{v}_k\}$ for some operator $A$ and suppose that they are linearly dependent. Absorbing any constants into the eigenvectors (multiplying an eigenvector by a non-zero scalar still produces an eigenvector), we can suppose that

$$\mathbf{v}_1 + \cdots + \mathbf{v}_k = \mathbf{0}$$

Taking a Euclidean geometric picture, you can imagine the vectors forming a closed curve of some sort when arranged head-to-tail. The conditions of this happening is rather stringent and the $\{\mathbf{v}_i\}$ being eigenvectors makes things worse.

If the vectors were linearly dependent, then we also have
$$A(\mathbf{v}_1 + \cdots + \mathbf{v}_k) = \lambda_1\mathbf{v}_1 + \cdots + \lambda_k\mathbf{v}_k = \mathbf{0}$$
This corresponds to scaling each vector by precisely $\lambda_i$ to form another closed curve. Since each $\lambda_i$ is distinct, we are not simply rescaling the original curve but producing a completely geometrically different closed curve. Intuitively, to me at least, this is very difficult.

To make matters even worse, we can repeat this procedure to obtain
$$\lambda_1^m\mathbf{v}_1 + \cdots + \lambda_k^m\mathbf{v}_k = \mathbf{0}$$
for any $m\in\mathbb{N}$, and each of these corresponds to a geometrically different curve.

More formally, suppose that $P$ is the matrix with columns formed from the eigenvectors. Then the eigenvectors being linearly dependent means that 
$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1\end{pmatrix},
\ \begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_k\end{pmatrix},
\ \begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1^2 \\ \lambda_2^2 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_k^2\end{pmatrix},
\ \begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1^3 \\ \lambda_2^3 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_k^3\end{pmatrix},
\ \cdots\right\}$$
are all vectors of the nullspace of which at most $k$-dimensional. It is very difficult (read impossible) to make the above family of vectors linearly dependent in the necessary way. So heuristically, it is "difficult" for eigenvectors of distinct eigenvalues to form a linearly dependent set and this somewhat justifies the theorem.

Comment: Sorry, the last paragraph confused me. What do you mean by "It is very difficult (read impossible) to make the above family of vectors linearly dependent in the necessary way."?

Comment: Because the nullspace is $k$-dimensional, any subset of $k+1$ vectors from that family will need to be linearly dependent. However, vectors of that form (each entry being some power of some number) are generally linearly independent.